# Tool rotation transformation and animation

Tags: javascript, animation, rotation, kineticjs

I 'm trying to do Toolse transformation to rotate the object , deploy object in degrees , but ran into a problem when the rotation of the object you want to animate .

The bottom line is that the animation object to be rotated for example at 1230 degrees or opposite , from 0 to 360 is not enough and need more range!

http://jsfiddles.net/hukNL/12/

In this example, I get the direction of the black point from 0 to 360 degrees looking where the black dot relative to the green square , but do not know how to make sure that the range grew up in a big way , or look less which way to rotate

Here for example the rotation of an object in one direction in 3D program [Image](http://sl-cms.com/i/korner-2013/a1181982d524b161f405f1ce41b4.png)

How to get this result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is to count the turns, multiply by a full turn, and add to the angle.

```
spins=0;
if turnClockWise
   spins++

if turnCounterClockWise
   spins--

angle = angle + spins*360;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8FUq/